# Effect of band around arms when bench pressing

Tags: health, form, shoulders, health-risk, bench-press

I worked out with some guys at my gym last night that introduced me to wearing a band just above the elbows (on the humerus) Below is a picture that partially resembles how I wore the band.

Imagine the band is slid down just passed the elbows on the humerus, and that is how I was wearing the band as I benched.  We had the bench at the smallest incline setting possible.

They told me wearing the band would keep the shoulders healthy.

I have never heard of this.  I actually felt that there was MORE stress on my shoulders with the band, because I could not go as wide as I wanted (I usually bench very wide).

If this does infact preserve the shoulders as they say, then how?

Or a refuting argument I would be happy to hear as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strategy looks like an emulation of the effect of a [slingshot](http://www.howmuchyabench.net/), a device which mainly sees use with people benching heavier weights (300+). I have not used this device, but I've spoken with users and they recommended it, mainly for dealing with shoulder injuries. When a shoulder injury occurs, especially for people benching these sorts of weights, it becomes difficult to do heavy reps as part of a workout, and the shoulder injury can become the limiting factor rather than the person's strength. According to the about section of the linked website, the slingshot (and presumably the band)

> work by stretching with you as you lower the weight to your chest, then when you are at the bottom of the lift, the Sling Shot gives you a little extra spring that allows you to get the weight moving again and complete the lift.

One of the users I spoke with benches 450+, and he said he doubted the product at first, but then stated that it allowed him to work through a shoulder injury which had limited him to reps at 225. Assuming that this band strategy is as effective as the slingshot, I would say that it makes sense for use when dealing with heavy reps, especially when recently injured, but in other scenarios may unnecessarily change parts of the motion.